# Magento - Add instructions to payment method

Tags: magento

I'd like to display some instructions/info whenever a user selects a certain payment method. How can I add this information to my payment module/method?

(I have another payment method that displays a form to fill in credit card data, but in this case I'd just like to display a bit of text)

Answer (score 0):

The Payment Method Model variable

```
protected $_infoBlockType;
```

is responsible for showing info block.
Check

```
class Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
```

and

```
class Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Cc extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info
```